# Why is the Stargate program run by the Air Force?

Tags: stargate

In the Stargate universe the Stargate program is run by the United States Air Force. But why was the Air Force given the reins on this project? Is it simply because the Stargate was located in [Cheyenne Mountain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheyenne_Mountain), which also houses the Cheyenne Mountain Air Force Station? Or is there an alternate reason, in or out of universe, for why the Air Force was chosen over another branch of the [United States Armed Forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Armed_Forces) or the [Canadian Forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_Forces) that make up the combined Cheyenne Mountain Directorate?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The United States Air Force has a unified [Space Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_Space_Command) and the headquarters for that particular division is fairly close to Cheyenne Mountain. In particular, you have the Fourteenth Air Force which is the space war fighting arm of the United State military.

The cryptoanalysis branch of the Air Force is now called the [Air Force Intelligence, Surveillance and Reconnaissance Agency.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_Intelligence,_Surveillance_and_Reconnaissance_Agency) They report to the Space Command. Given that this thing they found is made of exotic materials and covered with alien symbols, I'd think they'd want to take a look at it.

Also given that when the Stargate was discovered the Army and the Air Force were the same branch, it seems reasonable to assume that it simply got transferred to the Air Force when the two branches were separated. Particularly given that the [Signal Corps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Army_Signal_Corps) were the origin of the Air Force.

Comment: It was airforce before they knew what the stargate was ;)

Comment: So, I take it then that the 14th AF are the ones who are sitting on the F-302s then, yes? I so want in on the Stargate Program!  B)

Comment: It also makes more sense for the Air Force to study "Deep Space Radar Telemetry".

Comment: It also became regular procedure for them to fly drones (or UAVs, as they're called in the show) through the gate and surveil other planets. That is generally considered an Air Force job.

Comment: I wonder if the StarGate program will now be transferred to the Space Force.